# jee:jndi-lookup use to connect to database

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am working on spring application. I need to connect my application to database to get some records. I am failing to connect to database. It says "Table or view doesn't exist". I have the table and i can run the query in TOAD to view the records.

In dataSource-config.xml, i have the below line.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="cifDataSource" jndi-name="java:jdbc.datasource.CIFDataSource" resource-ref="true" />
```

What is the use of the above line. Do i need to create any object related to "CIFDataSource" . Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a DataSource configured in your Java EE application server.

You need to find this configuration and point it at the database that contains your tables.